# How to check dependencies, if a value may be null in JOI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have four user inputs: `reason1`, `date1`, `reason2`, `date2`. All may be null / undefined. If `date1` or `reason1` is not empty, `date1` and `reason1` are now mandatory. Same for `date2` and `reason2`. So the reasons are dependent of their dates and vice versa.

My tries so far:

```
var validationSchema = Joi.object.keys({
        date1: Joi.date().allow('').allow(null);
        date2: Joi.date().allow('').allow(null);
    })
    .with('reason1', 'date1')
    .with('reason2', 'date2')
;
```

wont work, because it's always true, due to `.allow(null)`. Remember, the dates may be `null`, if the reason is also `null`.

So I decided to "hack" the solution via arrays: The length of an array may be 0 (both null), 2 (both containing data) or 1 (only one of them containing data)

```
var data = req.body;
data.checkReason1 = []; data.checkReason2 = [];
(data.reason1 ? data.checkReason1.push(data.reason1) : null);
(data.date1 ? data.checkReason1.push(data.date1) : null);
(data.reason2 ? data.checkReason2.push(data.reason2) : null);
(data.date2 ? data.checkReason2.push(data.date2) : null);
var validationSchema = {
    checkReason1: Joi.array().length(0).length(2);  
    checkReason2: Joi.array().length(0).length(2);
}
```

wont work either, because multiple `.length()` on an array wont work with Joi.

//edit
thrid attempt is via `when`

```
var validationSchema = {
    date1: Joi.date().allow('').allow(null)
            .when('reason1', {is: Joi.string().min(1), then: Joi.date().required()}),
    date2: Joi.date().allow('').allow(null)
            .when('reason2', {is: Joi.string().min(1), then: Joi.date().required()})
};
```

but my `when` wont trigger at all..

Do you have another solution?